# How to display image from a blob on web

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am able to successfully upload images on azure blob storage but when i paste the absolute URI of the image into chrome it displays a xml error msg:
`The specified resource does not exist`.
I tried changing the content type from `applicaiton/octet-stream` to `image/jpeg` but still the same error. I am not sure how to display image in web with the URI. Do i need to make any changes in URI or i need to add any kind of permissions.

sample URI which i get on querying `blob.Uri.AbsoluteURI` is `https://<account name>.blob.windows.net/<container>/photo.JPG`

Thanks

Comment: Please check the container ACL. It should either be "Blob" or "Container" for the images to show in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have the right idea.  Can you ensure the access on the container is public (or Public Blob)?  You should be able to access the setting from the Azure Management page by navigating to the storage account and container you're using.

Comment: Ok, i tried that and able to access the image through URL in browser after setting permissions to public. But setting permission to public may not be the correct idea. Is there something similar to a session token which i can send with URL to display the image. The person who has that token is only able to view the image.

Comment: ok i got it finally from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453563/how-to-use-sharedaccesssignature-to-access-blobs

Comment: @SPB - since you figured it out, please close this question as a duplicate to the one you linked to. Just don't leave this question hanging out there in limbo. (never mind - I took care of it)

Comment: @David Yes i found the answer on the link provided, but i don't know how to close this question by marking it duplicate.